# Typescript and Symbol.for

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to type `Symbol.for`?

```
a.ts
------

const sym = Symbol.for('sym');

interface I {
  [sym]: number
}

export declare function f(i: I): void;
```

```
b.ts
------

const sym = Symbol.for('sym');

export class C {
  get [sym]() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

```
c.ts
------

import { C } from 'b';
import { f } from 'a';

const c = new C();
f(c);  // Type error
```

Currently using Typescript 3.6 so this may be supported in a later version of which I'm unaware.

Answer (score 1):

This works but seems like a kludge..

```
types/sym.d.ts
------

declare module 'sym' {
  const sym: unique symbol;
  export type Sym = typeof sym;
}
```

```
a.ts
------
import type { Sym } from 'sym';

const sym: Sym = Symbol.for('sym') as Sym;

interface I {
  [sym]: number
}

export declare function f(i: I): void;
```

```
b.ts
------
import type { Sym } from 'sym';

const symy: Sym = Symbol.for('sym') as Sym;

export class C {
  get [sym]() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

```
c.ts
------

import { C } from 'b';
import { f } from 'a';

const c = new C();
f(c);  // Type error
```

I'm interested to see if there are any cleaner ways of doing this without having to export the interface and have C implement it